What would be the long-term effects of a gas giant being hit by its moon?
I've been brainstorming ways to make the gas giants in my system more interesting, and as a result of this I thought of having one of them be hit by one of their moons (the reasons why are not relevant to this question)
Now I am trying to figure out what the long-term effects (if any) would be of this event on the planet itself. I am not considering the short-term effects because I am dating this impact to 10-60 million years ago.
The mass of the moon is 10000x less than that of the planet.
I have already thought of two ideas, but had to dismiss both:

The bands of the giant would change to diverge from the point of impact. This one I thought of because of the intense heat difference caused by the impact point, but I dismissed it because I feel that the Coriolis forces would overpower this difference, and even if it would be there, it would fade away after the time I had provided.


The ejecta from the event would coalesce into a moon. This one I had to dismiss because:
(1) Gas giants are made of mostly hydrogen, and hydrogen has an escape velocity that is too high to form into a geologically stable moon. (A hydrogen moon would be cool, though!)
(2) The moon is already very small compared to the planet. Even if a body could coalesce from the event, it would be even smaller and less massive than the original moon.

My current idea is that the weather of the planet would be affected in some way, but that is very vague and not helpful at all.
P.S. As KEY_ABRADE has pointed out, this is a much more significant impact event than Shoemaker-Levy.  It would be the equivalent of Ganymede hitting Jupiter, or Titan hitting Saturn
P.P.S Some people thought I was talking about the effects on the entire system. I have now edited the post to specify that I meant on only the planet. I am noting this so that the answer posted won't get hate for "missing the obvious." Probably wouldn't have happened, but better safe than sorry.

Note for those answering: this is larger than any impact event humanity has witnessed. It'd be the equivalent of a moon 10 times the mass of Jupiter's largest moon crashing into it — it's not like a Shoemaker-Levy.

@KEY_ABRADE I was about to paste link to Shoemaker. Darnit, mindreader! (That said, I still think it is a fascinating read, so I'll be leaving the link here anyway, hehe)

@KEY_ABRADE Oops, I had realized I had put 1000x instead of 10000x. I still think that it is much larger than a Shoemaker-Levy, though.

Yeah, the best estimates I can find for Shoemaker-Levy are 2 x 10^12 kg. Ganymede is about 1.5 x 10^23 kg whereas Jupiter is about 2 x 10^27 kg. If 10,000x, it's only one Ganymede-sized body crashing into a Jupiter-sized body, but that's still gigantic compared to Shoemaker-Levy — the impactor is about 450,000 times larger relative to the impactee than the Chicxulub impactor was to Earth.

Are you asking about a gradual decay and Roche limit shredding and perhaps a ring like Saturn? Or is this wizard steps in and causes a sudden orbit change causing an abrupt plunge?

@GaultDrakkor An abrupt plunge, although the wizard in this case is the introduction of a foreign body.

Are we considering only the effect on the gas giant, or the rest of the system as well?
Slamming a giant solid object into a gas giant of any kind will cause it to release tremendous amounts of radiation (well, most gas giants do so anyway, but we are talking about a sudden multifold increase). This would blast all nearby objects, especially the remaining moons with extra radiation, that would leave a semi-permanent mark in their lithic structure (like an inexplicable layer of irradiated rock). It might also be enough to trigger apocalyptic changes in their atmospheres (if they had any) or even affect their magnetospheres (again, if one existed). If the moons had any life on them, it is very likely it got fried by the event, but on the other hand, if there was no life on them previously, the radiation burst could provide just enough extra energy to thaw some of their water and kickstart life.

I was considering only the effects of the gas giant, but your answer is still appreciated.
